# Check value of a variable from every gameobject that attached by a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

I have a game object called "student" that has a script attached, then I duplicate it manually (ctrl+D) so every duplicated student object has the same script component. here's the script (not full because too long)

```
public class StudentScript : MonoBehaviour {

private Animator animator;
float sec;
public int m;
public GameManage gm;

void Start () {
    animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    sec = 0f;
    m = 0;
}

void Update () {
    sec+=Time.deltaTime;
    if (m == 5 && animator.GetInteger ("Behav") == 0) {
        animator.SetTrigger ("Finish");
    }
}

//this is called from another script
public void ResetStudentBehaviour(){
    if (animator.GetInteger ("Behav") != 0) {
        animator.SetInteger ("Behav", 0);
        sec = 0f;
        if (m < 5) {
            m++;
        }
    }else
        Debug.Log ("student done <3");
}
}
```

i want => if every student has m value m == 5, then game finished. what i've done so far is called StudentScript from GameManage script (public, so i have to set all the instance manually), then check the value of m from every student

```
public StudentScript stu1, stu2;
void Update () {
    if (stu1.m == 5 && stu2.m == 5) {
        StartCoroutine (ChangeScene());
    }
}
IEnumerator ChangeScene(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(5);
}
```

is there a simple way to check m value of all student object without using `if (stu1.m == 5 && stu2.m == 5)` because in every level, the number of student is different so i want to make a dynamic script for all level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `List<>` and add all your `StudentScript` objects to it. Then you could use `System.Linq`'s `All` method to check all of the elements in the list.

```
using System.Linq

//Add all your StudentScript objects to this list
List<StudentScript> studentScripts = new List<StudentScript>();

if(studentScripts.All(x => x.m == 5))
{
    StartCoroutine (ChangeScene());
}
```

This way you can use `StudentScripts.Add()` to add the scripts and it can be any size and all elements will still be checked. The `x => x.m == 5` part is called a lambda expression (just incase you didn't know). It's not as spooky as it looks.

If you don't want to use `Linq` and lambdas then you could just iterate over the list and update a variable. You could replace the `if` statement with:

```
private bool isGameOver()
{
    bool gameOver = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < studentScripts.Count; i++)
    {
        if (studentScripts[i].m != 5) 
        {
            gameOver = false;
            break;
        }
    }

  return gameOver;
}

void Update()
{
    if (isGameOver()) {
    StartCoroutine (ChangeScene());
    }
}
```

Comment: I was working on the second part of your answer but you posted it. I like that better because some of the linq functions wont work in iOS and some that work allocates memory a-lot.  The only thing remaining is putting the second part of your question in a function. Maybe boolean a function called `isGameOver`. It's not necessary but it will make the code re-usable. Now the update function will have less code.

Comment: Smart, I didn't know that about iOS. Again, thanks for the knowledge haha. I'll stick it in a funciton for completeness! I think `All` is ok for memory though? I'll profile it now and check.

Comment: sorry, but how to declare studentScripts?

Comment: @Eeva I made a small error in the fist section of code. It should be like so `List<StudentScript> studentScripts = new List<StudentScript>();`. I've updated the answer. Also @Programmer was right `All` assigns `40b` of memory every call. If you are calling it in the `Update` like this then go with the second method suggested!

Comment: @Eeva you will have to put `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of your script too.

Comment: @Eeva This answer has been edited a bunch. I fixed a silly error and so did programmer. Try it now and it should work.

Comment: @gjttt1 I don't know about `All` but `orderBy` and some others have problems due to AOT. Anyways I fixed the code a little bit by changing the function to bool and then return if game is over or not. The second method in your answer is highly recommended.  Memory allocation in GameEngines are not good at-all especially when they can be avoided. Also optimized the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all objects of a certain type that are in the scene, and then filter them with Linq or similar.

```
StudentScript[] studentsInScene = Object.FindObjectsOfType<StudentScript>();

if (studentsInScene.All(student => student.m == 5))
{
    StartCoroutine(ChangeScene());
}
```

FindObjectsOfType might not be quite as quick as a List you are managing yourself (though it might be), but if this is not your bottleneck (which it most likely isn't), then these few lines of code are much simpler to understand and thus preferrable.